# remove a class from any child of parent - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul` that it has an `id`. now, I would like to remove a class from any `li` from that `ul`. my class name is `active` :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-arrow" id="MainMenu">

<li class="active">...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="active">...</li>

</ul>
```

jQuery :

```
function changeTabs(tab) {
  //remove active class 
}
```

Comment: `$('#MainMenu > .active').removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will remove `active` class from all `li` inside your `ul`:

```
function changeTabs(tab) {

   $('#MainMenu').find('li').removeClass('active');

   //or
   $('#MainMenu li').removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('ul#MainMenu li').removeClass('active') ;
```

Comment: Since `id` is unique property, you need not mention `ul`. You can have a performance hit if you have large no of such ul.

Comment: Good to know, didn't kew about that. You're saying that in ul#MainMenu, jQuery parse first every ul and then filter on the ID that's it ? I always put ul just to make it more readable, but it's good to know thanks

Comment: yes it gets more readable but goes through extra iterations. Does not matter much until you have too many `ul`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find all the li of ul under your #MainMenu.

```
function changeTabs(tab) {
    //remove active class 
    $("#MainMenu").find("li").removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help in either cases of removing one class or in removing multiple classes.

```js
  
$("ul#MainMenu li").removeClass("active"); // delete all active class

//alert($("ul#MainMenu li.active").length) // find list of active classes.


//remove first element's active 
//$("ul#MainMenu li.active:first").removeClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-arrow" id="MainMenu">

<li class="active">a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li class="active">1</li>

</ul>
```